# Indenting in a Bash script printf command without the indent coming out in the output

Tags: bash, printf, indentation

I want to indent in my bash script so that my script looks more organized, but don't want the spaces to print.

If I have the command

```
printf "<image>
        <<include etc/image.conf>>
        </image>" > file.txt
```

I want file.txt to look like

```
<image>
<<include etc/image.conf>>
</image>
```

instead of

```
<image>
        <<include etc/image.conf>>
        </image>
```

The problem is that I don't want my script to look like this

```
While Loop
      If Statement
                printf "<image>
<<include etc/image.conf>>
</image>" > file.txt
                Command Here
      End If
End While
```

I just want it to look a little bit neater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the script more readable and prevent white spaces from getting in the way:

```
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "<image>" \
                      "<<include etc/image.conf>>" \
                      "</image>" > file.txt
```

Comment: Since printf repeats the format string for every argument, you can replace the format with just '%s\n' which looks a little cleaner and will allow you to include any number of lines after it.

Answer (score 5):

Use a heredoc:

```
cat <<- EOF > file.txt
    <image>
    <<include etc/image.conf>>
    </image>
EOF
```

(Note: the indentation should be tabs: one more reason that hard tabs are the correct choice of indentation.)  You can use any number of tabs in the indentation, and they will be stripped by bash before being passed to `cat`.  The indentation is also stripped by the delimeter, so your final result will look like:

```
While Loop
      If Statement
                cat <<- EOF > file.txt 
                        <image>
                        <<include etc/image.conf>>
                        </image>
                EOF
                Command Here
      End If
End While
```

Note that this will perform variable expansion, etc. on the text.  If you want to avoid that, just quote the delimiter.  eg, `cat <<- 'EOF' > file.txt`

Comment: I stopped using tabs a long time ago.  I don't like any logic that depends upon the white spaces.  Otherwise, this would have been a superb solution.

Comment: If you insist on avoiding tabs (big mistake, IMO and since you have carefully crafted your code so that the choice is irrelevant it won't be difficult to change!), you can get almost the same functionality with `sed 's/^ *//' << EOF > file.txt` and let sed strip the leading whitespace.  The drawback is that this does not allow any indentation on the final delimiter.